# Rspec Factory Girl Model Singular Plural (uninitialized constant [ModelName])

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Getting an error when I try to test my model called Settings, I have a feeling it has something to do with singular and plural model names, but how do I fix it?

here is the spec settings_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Settings do
  let!(:settings) { Factory(:settings) }

  describe "has a valid factory" do
    specify { should be_an_instance_of(Settings) }
  end

end


1) Settings has a valid factory 
     Failure/Error: let!(:settings) { Factory(:settings) }
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant Setting
     # ./spec/models/settings_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My model is truly named Settings, the file name is settings.rb. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It expects model name to be `Setting`. Either rename model `app/model/setting.rb` to `Setting` or goto the file `config/initializers/inflections.rb` and add settings to uncountable configuration.

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable %w(settings)
end
```

Comment: just curious if you would know off the top of your head if this could have possible side effects elsewhere in my app?